# How to calculate cumulative value using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Where did I go wrong here? The cum_duration should produce the cumulative of activity_duration but it return the same value with the activity_duration instead. How to get the cumulative value?

```
 SELECT
      fact_daily_summary.day_date,
      fact_daily_summary.day_number,
      fact_activity.activity_duration/3600 AS activity_duration,
      (SELECT
        SUM(fc.activity_duration)/3600
      FROM fact_activity fc
      WHERE fc.fact_activity_uid = fact_activity.fact_activity_uid
      AND fc.fact_activity_uid <= fact_activity.fact_activity_uid
      GROUP BY fact_activity.fact_activity_uid
      ORDER BY fact_activity.fact_activity_uid)
      AS cum_duration,
      depth_md_msl
    FROM 
         fact_daily_summary,
         fact_activity
    WHERE fact_activity.daily_uid = fact_daily_summary.daily_uid
    AND fact_daily_summary.operation_uid = fact_operation_summary.operation_uid
```

Results

```
day_date             day_number  activity_duration  cum_duration  depth_md_msl  
-------------------  ----------  -----------------  ------------  --------------
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.500000      0.500000        -1025.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    1.500000      1.500000        -1025.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.500000      0.500000        -1025.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    1.500000      1.500000        -1017.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                   19.000000     19.000000         -998.65
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.499722      0.499722         -998.65
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.249722      0.249722         -998.65
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.249722      0.249722         -998.55
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.500000      0.500000        -1025.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    1.500000      1.500000        -1025.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.500000      0.500000        -1025.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    1.500000      1.500000        -1017.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                   19.000000     19.000000         -998.65
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.499722      0.499722         -998.65
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.249722      0.249722         -998.65
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.249722      0.249722         -998.55
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.500000      0.500000        -1025.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    1.500000      1.500000        -1025.15
2012-06-17 00:00:00  2                    0.500000      0.500000        -1025.15
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use the date in the subquery.  Well, also the `group by` is unnecessary:

```
SELECT fds.day_date, fds.day_number,
       fa.activity_duration/3600 AS activity_duration,
       (SELECT SUM(fc2.activity_duration)/3600
        FROM fact_activity fc2
        WHERE fc2.fact_activity_uid = fa.fact_activity_uid AND
              fc2.day_date <= fa.day_date
       ) as cum_duration,
       depth_md_msl
    FROM fact_operation_summary fos JOIN
         fact_daily_summary fds
         ON fds.operation_uid = fos.operation_uid JOIN
         fact_activity fa
         ON fa.daily_uid = fds.daily_uid;
```

Note I also fixed the `FROM` clause to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Got this error

<e>Query: SELECT fds.day_date, fds.day_number, fa.activity_duration/3600 AS activity_duration, (SELECT SUM(fc2.activity_duration)/3600 FRO...

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'fa.activity_duration' in 'field list'

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.001 sec

Comment: i forgot to tell you that  fc2.day_date <= fa.day_date does not exist in the fact_activity table but its in the fact_daily_summary table so it cannot use that in the query...but anyway if i use fc2.start_datetime <= fa.start_datetime which is in the fact_Activity_table the cum_duration still return the same value as the activity_duration

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MySQL 8, cumulative sums are ideally calculated using [window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/). Your query could be written as follows:

```
SELECT
  fds.day_date,
  fds.day_number,
  fa.activity_duration / 3600 AS activity_duration,

  -- Window function here
  SUM (fa.activity_duration / 360) OVER (PARTITION BY fa.fact_activity_uid ORDER BY day_date)
    AS cum_duration,
  depth_md_msl
FROM 
  fact_daily_summary fds,
  fact_activity fa,
  fact_operation_summary fos
WHERE fa.daily_uid = fds.daily_uid
AND fds.operation_uid = fos.operation_uid
```